# Django Easy Maps dynamic values

Tags: django, google-maps, django-templates, django-template-filters

I am using Django Easy Maps from

```
https://bitbucket.org/kmike/django-easy-maps
```

The example works fine as long as I keep the address hard-coded

```
{% easy_map "Russia, Ekaterinburg, Mira 32" 350 200 %}
```

It does not work if dynamic addresses are used

```
{% easy_map "Brazil, object.state , object.city  " 350 200 %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work this way. It's like specifying variable name inside some string in normal python code, and expecting it to evaluate into that variable value.

`easy_map` tag doesn't provide way to parametrize string, neither django templates. You should parse that data outside of templates (for example as `@property` inside your object) and provide it into `easy_map` tag like this:

```
{% easy_map object.map_location 350 200 %}
```

that means without quotes, so it will be considered as variable, not as string.

Comment: thanks.. it works only if there is object.address, it throws errors if there are object.city object.state